# what is the equivalent of scp for the serial console?

Tags: ssh, serial, uart, scp

I am configuring my raspberry pi device of the serial console (like this https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-5-using-a-console-cable/overview)

How can I do the equivalent of scp?  (copy files to the raspberry pi)

Currently I am just going `cat > newfile.py` and then pasting in the file content.

Maybe the following matrix will explain what I am missing:

```
over network                    | over serial
--------------------------------------------------------------
ssh pi@192.168.1.10             | picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyU*
--------------------------------------------------------------
scp script.py pi@192.168.1.10:~ | ????????????????
```

---

additional stuff:

- I would like to put this in a script, so a non interactive way would be preferable.
- All of your suggestions sound great.. but an example would be really handy.

Comment: You are essentially back to the old modem days.  Does picocom support zmodem?  If yes, install "rz" and "sz" on both ends and just upload.

Comment: I was tempted to suggest xmodem but seriously I could not recommend a 1970s protocol. If you really are limited to a serial link this family of protocols at least has a proven track record. I wouldn't even use scp - FTP is much easier and more reliable.

Comment: How about running a point-to-point IP connection over serial (with pppd and wvdial) then run a standard ssh session over that link.

Comment: would that be done using the same uart adapter and usb?  can you point me in the right direction to get started?

Comment: Your parallel to ssh here is incorrect; see my comment on Dmitri's answer.  If you want to send a file while the serial port is configured *as a console*, then what you are really asking is parallel to "How can I send a file *within* an ssh login session?" because if the console is enabled, it cannot be turned off except by restarting the system (as far as I know).

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your approach for individual text files. For a binary file (or a large number of files/directories which you'd pack together with `tar/gzip`), you can use `base64` to encode them as text:

Receiver (Pi over `picocom`):

```
cat | base64 -di > file
```

Sender (another terminal on the PC):

```
cat file | base64 > /proc/`pidof picocom`/fd/0
```

Also note that if you want to try out X/Y/ZMODEM (which will be about 30% faster than `gzip`/`base64`), the client in Debian goes by the name `lrzsz` and can be installed with `apt`. Other apps with ZMODEM support are `cutecom`/`minicom`.

Comment: You are right: it is better to use mainstream Debian package. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: I don't think this will work if the port is configured as a serial *console*, ie., a login.  Using the port for just data this way is the equivalent of scp to ssh, because scp **doesn't use a console interface**.  It uses the same network protocol to send file data that ssh uses to establish a console/terminal based login; the parallel would be UART.  However, UART is more restricted in that it is as if you could configure sshd to allow logins **or** file transfer but not both.   This is why there are those wacky modem protocols.

Comment: @goldilocks You can still push text though a tty. Perhaps a simple `cat | base64 -di > file` on the Pi side will work.

Comment: True. But you can't capture that as far as I know.  It isn't the stdin of a process you run in that tty, so `cat > file` won't work.  It's the stdin of the getty or shell process, I think, since if you send ANSI control codes through to a terminal the output will appear appropriately formatted.  Unfortunately they probably don't have those for file transfer.

Comment: @goldilocks You're right, I got it all mixed up. Hopefully my last edit is more to the point.

Answer (score 2):

Although old fashioned, Picocom supports filetransfer, x-modem, y-modem, z-modem and ascii-xfr. If I where you, i'd go for z-modem. The package you are looking for is `lrzsz` (and not`zmodem` as I stated earlier). Note that it operates a bit different from `scp`.